# Ignore click on DataGridView if click is done on scrollbars

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, click, scrollbar

When the user clicks on my `DataGridView` I would like to check whether they have clicked on the scroll bars or not. If so, I do not want the click to be triggered so that all clicks on the scroll bars will be ignored. How do I check this inside my `DataGridView`'s click event?

NB. by "clicking on scrollbars", I mean all the area in a scroll bar control and not just the handle.